# How to insert a changed row using SnowFlake's Merge command?

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Help with merge in SnowFlake
On match where tgt.Hashvalue <> src.Hashvalue
I want to End the current record (EndDate = lastday of lastmonth, and currentInd = 0)
I'd then like to insert a new row for the changed record. On match states it only allows 'Update' or 'Delete'

Can someone show me how to accomplish this?

```
MERGE INTO "a"."b"."target_prd" AS tgt
USING "a"."b"."source_stg" AS src
ON tgt.DNumber = src.DNumber and tgt."Curr_Ind" = 1

--************************************************************************************************
--UPDATE
-- If hashvalue in source table != hashvalue in target table and CurrentInd in target = 'Y'
WHEN MATCHED AND tgt.hashvalue != src.hashvalue AND tgt."Curr_Ind" = '1' THEN
    UPDATE SET 
        tgt.ChangeType = 'Update',
        tgt."End_Date" =  LAST_DAY(ADD_MONTHS(TO_DATE('20230801', 'YYYYMMDD'),-1))
       ,tgt."Curr_Ind" = 0     
WHEN MATCHED AND tgt.hashvalue != src.hashvalue THEN
        INSERT (
              FILE_DATE_YYYYMM,
             "Start_Date",
             "End_Date",
             "Curr_Ind",
             "Location",
```